# How to combine set cookie and redirection in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

It's about this .htaccess ruleset:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lc_dsg 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/cookie_consent\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/gtapp\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=REFCOOKIE:true]
RewriteRule .* - [E=FILENAME:https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}]
Header set Set-Cookie "lc_ref=%{FILENAME}e ; path=/; secure" env=REFCOOKIE
```

This ruleset works as expected, but I need to add a redirection to this ruleset. If I add a redirection to the ruleset redirection and setting cookie works, but the cookie value is empty. It seems redirection goes to fast to set the value. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lc_dsg [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/cookie_consent\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/gtapp\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=REFCOOKIE:true]
RewriteRule .* - [E=FILENAME:https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}]
Header set Set-Cookie "lc_ref=%{FILENAME}e ; path=/; secure" env=REFCOOKIE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lc_dsg [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cookie_consent.php [R=302,L]  env=REFCOOKIE
```